# .Net Xml Deserialization - Support Multiple Namespaces

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to support XML deserialization of two very similar, yet different xml files.

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lr:LogReport xmlns:dcml="http://www.x1.org/schemas/Types/"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.x3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:lr="http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.x3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.x3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <lr:reportDate>2010-03-05T07:00:52-08:00</lr:reportDate>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<LogReport xmlns="http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord" 
    xmlns:dcml="http://www.x1.org/schemas/Types" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.x3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:lr="http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.x3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.x3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord ./LogRecord.xsd  http://www.x1.org/schemas/Types ./Types.xsd">
    <lr:reportDate>2010-02-26T07:00:02-08:00</lr:reportDate>
```

Class Definition:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-4/2008/LogRecord"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("LogReport", [Namespace]:="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-4/2008/LogRecord", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class LogReport
```

Files matching File1 fail while files matching File2 succeed.  The key difference is the trailing slash two of the namespace definitions.

Code Sample:

```
Dim oLogReport As New LogReport
Dim oType As System.Type = oLogReport.GetType
Dim oReader As System.Xml.XmlReader = Nothing
Dim oSerializer As New XmlSerializer(oType)
oReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(sFileName)
oLogReport = CType(oSerializer.Deserialize(oReader), LogReport)
```

Error from File1:

```
{"<LogReport xmlns='http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord/'> was not expected."}
```

Already tried:  [How do I specify XML serialization attributes to support namespace prefixes during deserialization in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254544/how-do-i-specify-xml-serialization-attributes-to-support-namespace-prefixes-durin)

These files come from a third-party so I cannot change the serialization process.  Is there a way I can support both xml formats?  Do I need two separate classes?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't actually see a difference between the two XML samples. What do you believe is the difference?

Comment: "The key difference is the trailing slash on two of the namespace definitions."

Ex:

xmlns:lr="http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord/"

vs.

xmlns:lr="http://www.x.org/schemas/LogRecord"

Answer (score 2):

Two separate class models is an option, although admittedly not a very good one.

Do you actually get these files as XML that you then process in code, or are you using smoe sort of proxy that's supposed to auto-deserialize the XML?

If you're doing your own deserialization, I would consider creating a simple XSL Transform to convert the namespaces in-memory before executing the deserialization.  A transform to simply replace one pair of namespaces with another pair will be pretty short and simple.

Comment: According to the LogRecord.xsd of the S430-4-2008 standard, the namespace is `http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-4/2008/LogRecord` without the trailing slash. It seems that the File1 is incorrect. To solve the problem, do a text find & replace, and correct the namespace (in-memory or on-disk). You should also contact the supplier of the File1 to correct the namespace. There is a standard, so they should follow it.

Comment: Aargh it seems that the S430-4-2008.pdf actually lists the namespace as being with a trailing slash. So File1 is ... uh ... also correct? xsd and all sample files do **not** have a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

Got around to attempt another fix for this, as I did not like having to do a find & replace inside the xml file.

So here it is --works on my machine--

I first generated the `logRecordType` and `logRecordHeaderType` classes using **xsd.exe**. Note that I only need to parse the `logRecordHeader` elements, so there is some extra work here. But the fix basically is to use the `FixupNameTable` so that every occurrence of the namespace with trailing slash is replaced with the one without it.

```
namespace DolbyService.Schemas
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public partial class logRecordType
{
    public const string xmlns_lr = "http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-4/2008/LogRecord";
    public const string xmlns_dcml = "http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/433/2008/dcmlTypes";


    public static IEnumerable<logRecordHeaderType> Parse(Stream xmlfile)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.NameTable = new FixupNameTable();
        using (var rdr = XmlReader.Create(xmlfile, settings))
        {
            var headerSerialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(logRecordHeaderType));

            while (rdr.ReadToFollowing(logRecordHeaderType.LogRecordHeader, logRecordType.xmlns_lr))
            {
                using (var subreader = rdr.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    var ok = headerSerialize.CanDeserialize(subreader);
                    var logRecordHeader = headerSerialize.Deserialize(subreader);
                    yield return logRecordHeader as logRecordHeaderType;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class FixupNameTable : XmlNameTable
{
    private NameTable _table = new NameTable();

    public override string Add(string key)
    {
        key = ReplaceKey(key);
        return _table.Add(key);
    }

    private static string ReplaceKey(string key)
    {
        if (key.StartsWith(logRecordType.xmlns_lr)) key = logRecordType.xmlns_lr;
        if (key.StartsWith(logRecordType.xmlns_dcml)) key = logRecordType.xmlns_dcml;
        return key;
    }

    public override string Add(char[] array, int offset, int length)
    {
        return _table.Add(array, offset, length);
    }

    public override string Get(string key)
    {
        key = ReplaceKey(key);
        return _table.Get(key);
    }

    public override string Get(char[] array, int offset, int length)
    {
        return _table.Get(array, offset, length);
    }
}

[XmlRoot(logRecordHeaderType.LogRecordHeader, Namespace = logRecordType.xmlns_lr, IsNullable = false)]
public partial class logRecordHeaderType
{
    public const string LogRecordHeader = "LogRecordHeader";

    private static XmlSerializer _ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(logRecordHeaderType));

    public static logRecordHeaderType Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        return _ser.Deserialize(xmlReader) as logRecordHeaderType;
    }

    public static bool CanDeserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        return _ser.CanDeserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}

public class HeaderComparer : IEqualityComparer<logRecordHeaderType>
{
    public bool Equals(logRecordHeaderType x, logRecordHeaderType y)
    {
        return x.EventID == y.EventID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(logRecordHeaderType obj)
    {
        return obj.EventID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the namespaces are different, then the XML is different.