# Load unsafe characters into XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, string, soap

I have a computer generated string full of 'unsafe' (\n,\t, etc.) characters, how do I load it into a XmlDocument such as this?

```
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<soap:Body>
 <HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
    <parameter1>"+ generatedstring + @"</parameter1>
 </HelloWorld>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>");
```

Comment: I added an alternative in my answer that you might find interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this using the api provided for you:

```
var data = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
               xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
               xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<soap:Body>
 <HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
    <parameter1></parameter1> <!-- we'll fill this in below -->
 </HelloWorld>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>";

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
var names = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
names.AddNamespace("a", "http://tempuri.org/");
xmlDoc.LoadXml(data);
var containingElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//a:HelloWorld/a:parameter1", names);
var textToAdd = "\r\n\t&<>"; //nasties
containingElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(textToAdd)); //no problem
```

If you instead moved to the newer/better `XDocument`, you can do it in a somewhat terser fashion:

```
XNamespace a = "http://tempuri.org/";
XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(data);
d.Descendants(a + "parameter1").Single().Value = "\r\n\t&<>";
```