# How do I declare namespace prefix for attribute in .NET?

Tags: c#, xml

The problem is similar to this:

[How do I specify XML serialization attributes to support namespace prefixes during deserialization in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254544/how-do-i-specify-xml-serialization-attributes-to-support-namespace-prefixes-duri)

but specifically for attribute.
I have something like:

`<person xmlns:a="http://example.com" xmlns:b="http://sample.net">
    <a:fName a:age="37">John</a:fName>
    <b:lName>Wayne</b:lName>
</person>`

and I can't find a way to put the prefix to the attribute "age".

How the solution proposed in the link above must be changed to reach the goal? I tried different solution without success.

Comment: You consider people to be ageless, but there first names to have an age? Interesting...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ha ha!! you are right, but might be he gave pseudo XML that suits his requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace XMLSer
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                FName fname = new FName { Age = 16.5, Text = "John" };

            Person person = new Person();

            person.fname = fname;
            person.lname = "Wayne";

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            ser.Serialize(Console.Out, person);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://example.com")]
        public FName fname;

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://sample.com")]
        public string lname;

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        public Person()
        {
            xmlns.Add("a", "http://example.com");
            xmlns.Add("b", "http://sample.com");
        }
    }

    public class FName
    {
        [XmlAttribute("age")]
        public double Age;

        [XmlText]
        public string Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but your code generate the following xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://example.com" xmlns:b="http://sample.com">
  <a:fname age="16.5">John</a:fname>
  <b:lname>Wayne</b:lname>
</person>

and unfortunatly "age" still does not contain the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the same as in the linked example (but using the `XmlAttributeAttribute` instead of the `XmlElementAttribute`). Your property declaration would be something like:

```
[XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com")]
public decimal Age { get; set; }
```

Further details and examples for the `XmlAttributeAttribute` are on the [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.90%29).

To get the attribute on the `fName` element I think that you would need the age to be a property of the first name property. Is the attribute supposed to be on the `fName` element or on the `person` element?

Comment: I tried to insert the namespace but the result is the same. No prefix on the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to specify "xsi:schemaLocation" as an attribute.

I fixed it doing the next:

```
[XmlElement("xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public string Xsi { get; set; }    

[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }
```

Note: Both NameSpaces must match.