# How to change WebMethod XML output for ASP.NET Webservice, specifically namespace declaration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm developing an ASP.NET Webservice (not WCF) for a given client. This is one of those situations, where you can not change anything at the client.

The client sends the following XML to request a method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:cometxsd="http://werk-ii.de/soap/comet/Schema"
                   xmlns:comet="http://werk-ii.de/soap/comet"
                   xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"
                   xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
                   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                   xmlns:xmime5="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://soap.comet.werkii.com/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:login xsi:type="ns1:login">
      <user>myusername</user>
      <password>mypassword</password>
      <client>whatever</client>
      <language>de</language>
    </ns1:login>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My Service provides the login-Method like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://soap.comet.werkii.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class CometService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(MessageName = "login")]
    [return: XmlElement("return")]
    public LoginResult Login (string user, string password, string client, string language)
    {
        return new LoginResult() {
            ResultCode = 0,
            SessionId = user + "-" + password + "-" + client + "-" + language
        };
    }
}

public class LoginResult
{
    [XmlElement("resultCode")]
    public int ResultCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("sessionId")]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

If I start the service, it tells me what SOAP 1.1 code I have to send as a request, that ist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <login xmlns="http://soap.comet.werkii.com/">
      <user>string</user>
      <password>string</password>
      <client>string</client>
      <language>string</language>
    </login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I use this code - as told by the service - from another test client (i wrote one in PHP), everything works fine an I get a result. But when I send the code from the beginning (which is what the real client will send), **the method is called but all 4 arguments are null**.

From an XML view, in my opinion both requests are the same. The only difference is, where the namespace is defined and if elements use the ns1 prefix. This should not make any difference, when the service reads it as XML. Maybe I'm wrong.

Perhaps the 4 arguments in the first XML have a different namespace (none) than the method (ns1). Can that be the reason why all arguments are null? How would I change the namespace for the arguments only?

When I change only the method lines in XML - replacing `<ns1:login xsi:type="ns1:login">` with `<login xmlns="http://soap.comet.werkii.com/">` and also the closing tag - it works! So the service seems not to understand my request, if the method element uses a namespace prefix, though the namespace is properly defined in the root element.

I tried the following to change the XML format which the service expects:

- System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute - no effect at all
- XmlNamespaceDeclarationsAttribute as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254544/how-do-i-specify-xml-serialization-attributes-to-support-namespace-prefixes-duri/1260387#1260387) - which seems not to work because it is made for manipulating complex types, not the service class or a method

So the question is, **how can I tell my service to accept the XML from the first example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to know that parameters can also have Attributes:

```
public LoginResult Login (
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")] string user,
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")] string password,
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")] string client,
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")] string language)
{
    return new LoginResult() {
        ResultCode = 0,
        SessionId = user + "-" + password + "-" + client + "-" + language
    };
}
```

That's the solution to put the parameters into the global namespace – problem solved.