# How to add special character to XmlElement attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute

I want to add special character to XmlElement attribute. I have a class

```
public class Sitemap
{
    [XmlElement("loc:url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

After execute Xml I have this snippet with encode charater

```
<loc_x003A_url>XmlURL</loc_x003A_url>
```

The character [:] was converted to [*x003A*]

This result I expect:

```
 <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <loc:url>StringURL</loc:url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254544/how-do-i-specify-xml-serialization-attributes-to-support-namespace-prefixes-duri

Comment: I guess you want to actually use a namespace. If you really want a colon to be part of your name: it will not work. It's reserved for namespaces.

Comment: The result is child node. It isn't namespace. I found solution for namespace  your comment

Comment: see following webpage : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references