# ASP.NET Web API and XML Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

I am developing a Web API and I have a model as below:

```
   public class Customer
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public decimal Age { get; set; }
    }
```

And my controller is:

```
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {

        public Customer Get()
        {
            return new Customer {Name="Mike",Age=22.0M };
        }

    }
}
```

When I set accept:application/xml my result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>Mike</Name>
    <Age>22.0</Age>
</Customer>
```

As I am developing it for a customer, I need my xml to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cu:Customer xmlns:cu="http://www.mywebsite.com/test">
    <Name>Mike</Name>
    <Age>22.0</Age>
</cu:Customer>
```

I can do that if I create an `XmlSerializer` and manually call `Serialize` fuction and then return the result as string, but I need the function to return Customer as return value.

Comment: I hope this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254544/how-do-i-specify-xml-serialization-attributes-to-support-namespace-prefixes-duri) answer could help you. It appears to be what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication128
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("cu", "http://www.mywebsite.com/test");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));

            CustomerController controller = new CustomerController();

            serializer.Serialize(writer, controller.Get(), namespaces);
        }
    }
    public class ApiController
    {
    }
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {

        public Customer Get()
        {
            return new Customer { Name = "Mike", Age = 22.0M };
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Customer", Namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/test")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
        public decimal Age { get; set; }
    }

}
```